# If I set hours, minutes and seconds to 0 in a Date, the day decreases by one..

Tags: java, android, date

First of all, I know I can use `Calendar`, but I want to understand this problem and learn to solve it.

I have a `Date` with the current date. I want to set hours, minutes and seconds to 0. I do it with this code:

```
        current_date.setHours(0);
        current_date.setMinutes(0);
        current_date.setSeconds(0);
```

Something is going wrong because if I do that, the day gets decreased by 1, for example, if today is 31, the day gets set to 30.

why? How can it be solved with `Date` (without using `Calendar`, I want to learn how to solve this problem by the hard way). Thanks

Comment: @LukeTaylor Why not? There are plenty of potentially valid question titles that include the word "why".

Comment: Your question title is legit now, it was all kangfu before that. :P

Comment: This code does not change the day; http://ideone.com/uE7Yx ?

Comment: day is not changing for me..And why to use depricated methods if option is available..

Comment: Is this issue constrained to android devices, since the java.util.Date does not replicate this (as per the link in my previous comment)?

Comment: Considering it's a set of deprecated methods, it seems to be a moot point of little value to the community. If you want to know why the behaviour you're seeing is occurring, check the source code - it's readily available and is unlikely to be an overwhelming amount for such simple methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing...

I guess it has to do with time-zone.

When you set HMS to 0 you are not setting them according to your time zone, but according to UTC (not 100% sure, but...). So the resulting date is not:

```
0:0:0 YOUR LOCAL
```

but

```
0:0:0 GMT
```

and that's a day before if you are on America.

Try to set minutes to `-yourDate.getTimezoneOffset()` (try with positive value if it doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the implementation of these methods. They use a gregorian calendar. The error might come from that interaction.

Note: The set methods are all deprecated since JDK 1.1 [see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Comment: If that's true, it's a convention that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: try to set the hours, minutes and seconds to zero. Check if decrementing the long (0:00:00 to 23:59:59) is resulting in a smaller day.

Comment: I can't replicate the situation being described in the question, personally. Initialising a Date object gives me the time at which it was initialised, calling `setHours(0)`, `setMinutes(0)` and `setSeconds(0)` provides me with a Date object that's midnight today, then subtracting 1000 from the long value (a second earlier) gives me a Date that's 23:59:59 yesterday.

Comment: @AndroidUser99: How to solve? *Do not use deprecated methods if there is already an alternative*. All the methods in Date were deprecated for a reason - they do not work properly (the Javadoc is quite clear about that).

Comment: yes but i want to understan a way to solve this with date, only for learn it

Comment: So in essence, you think we can tell you how you can fix what the JRE developers wrote off as not fixable (the Date API)? If you think its *not complicated*, then you may read Jon Skeets [OMG Ponies](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx), just scroll down to the part where he talks about time, if you don't want to read all of it.